# How can I lag a computer in c#? CREATE lag!

Tags: c#

This is an odd question, I understand. I also assumed it would be simple, because lord knows I have created my share of infinite loops.

I'm trying to cause a slight PC lag in C# - specifically I need to create a 'choppy mouse' situation system wide (not just the sandboxed exe).

The little app can't crash the computer! The lag should be able to run for 2-10 seconds ish - then stop.

What I have tried so far:
-Spawning numerous threads that save data (filled up memory and cause PF usage, no real lag).

-Spawning TONS of threads (lag at first, but then none when treads are re-spawned again - as if the second time the OS is ready).

-Spawning threads that take several screenshots (the screenshots don't seem to lag).

None of these have worked - any ideas?

Optional back story (optional):
The reason for the application, without divulging any company information, is to cover up a laggy background process in a production environment. We have tried to speed the app up, or improve the computers with no results. There is an abuse case that is present when production workers associate a lag with this background application running. The goal is to disassociate this lag ... by creating a similar one at random times sparingly.

Clarification:
The original background app is not home grown (fyi) the only real solution would to be purchase 1000s of new boxes. The company is going with the cheaper 'hide the background app' ... 'solution'. I know...

Comment: Dear god in heaven, why? So you're trying to train users that this is normal? For shame! Seriously, I'm a tad bit taken aback. I award you no points and may god have mercy on your soul.

Comment: Uh wait... so you are trying to trick the users that the background lag is NOT your app? Instead of building this, I would spend the effort to fix the problem instead of waging psychological warfare against users.

Comment: So instead of asking "how can I keep a responsive UI or computer when a background process hangs" you ask "how can I randomly lock the computer so nobody questions this hanging background process?"

Comment: Now that's good. Rather than fix the real problem, misdirect the users so they think the problem's somewhere else. "Well, I guess I just need a faster computer." I'm not going to downvote the question since it meets guidelines. But I think that, as a software developer, you're doing us all a great disservice going down this road.

Comment: Trust me, I would much rather fix the problem... but it's not in the 'budget'. I could rant about this for hours (and have too!)

Comment: Yet you have a "cover-up" budget? Interesting. Work for the government, per chance?

Comment: I should totally put this on the daily WTF. maybe I'll submit my code there when I'm done... because it will be the spawn of all evil.

Comment: @Justin: It took me three clicks to figure out that you work for Thales Group. You might want to hide your identity better before posting stuff like this.

Comment: I don't work there anymore... and If I did its ok to know about it :). I now work at HarrisDecima - its not a covert secret !

Comment: I gave you a -1 for even considering doing this project. Sorry.

Comment: This request isn't as unusual as it seems. I worked for a large multinational a few years back, when a sales guy was made manager of our development team so he would "technical experience". I wrote a database application which (initially) produced a small number of reports from a huge amount of data, this was put on a box perfectly capable for its specification. However all users the spec kept increasing and all users tended to run all reports at the same time. So rather than increasing the hardware our manager wanted to put a waitfor pause in the code at non-busy times..

Comment: @Paul Sasik - Heh. That's one of my employers' competitors. Now I'm feeling even better about "helping" him. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a background app that randomly calls the Windows BlockInput API at a desired interval. This allows your app to have as small a footprint as possible preventing it from taking up CPU cycles and memory.

More information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290.aspx

That said, I agree with the other posts / comments that this is addressing the symptoms and not the problem.

EDIT: code example

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace LagTimer
{
    class Program
    {
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern bool BlockInput([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(LagTick);
            t.Start();

            while (true) { } // Prevent the app from exiting
        }

        static void LagTick()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                BlockInput(true);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
                BlockInput(false);

                // TODO: Randomize time in between ticks
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                // TODO: Add logic for when to "sputter" the mouse
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an awesome idea - I'm trying this now. Way easier on the boxes than wasted computing numbers.

Comment: PERFECT! this lags a *mouse* beautifully, and easily. I'm using this.

Comment: Ethical / unethical debate: get the pitchforks. Business patchwork solution: complete!

Comment: Glad to hear so. Note that it also blocks the keyboard input during that lag "spike."

Answer (score 0):

You could make a thread that has an infinite loop, and every X seconds raises an event that the UI Thread catches.  The UI thread could then call Thread.Sleep for however long you want.

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE DON'T DO THIS**

That said, it could be accomplished by creating a number of threads that matches the number of logical processor cores in the system, set the processor affinity of each thread so that there's one per core, and then just have each thread run code like this:

```
int i = rand();
while (!timeLimitExpired())
{
    i += rand() % i;
}
```

The purpose of the rand() call is to keep a compiler optimization from realizing that your loop doesn't actually do anything and optimizing it away, and the purpose of the modulo operation is to prevent creating an overflow (exception) (you could use simple division as well).

Because I don't think you should do, I won't share the code on how to determine the number of processor core or detect thread affinity.  Instead, *please please please* fix your app. It's probably as simple as adding a sleep() call in the middle of a tight loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to make a timed busy-loop. The simplest way to do that is just a tight loop that checks the clock and exits when a certian delta of time has passed.

Now, on a typical PC you might not see any "lag" when this happens. Why? Well there are a couple of reasons.

1. Multiple CPUs. If you don't do this on every CPU, then there's a free CPU for the OS to use and you might not notice the difference. To make sure you are using every CPU, I'd suggest creating a process to run your "cpu eater" with the CPU affinity set or CPU 0, and then another for each other CPU the system has.
2. Task priorities. Generally things like the desktop are given a higher priority than background tasks. If you want to keep your program from being pre-empted by that, you need to make it a very high priority.

*Note: if you make your task high-priority, and then somehow set it up to run on startup or login, I am not responsible for any damage you do to your machine or OS reinstalls you are forced to perform. Also, chewing up large amounts of CPU for extended periods can cause PCs with stock cooling setups to overheat. This causes crashes and sometimes permanent damage.*

---

I would like to add that, while we developers don't have to sign onto any code of ethics to get professional licenses like Doctors, Lawyers, and some engineers must do, there are still times when we have an obligation to refuse to carry out unethical requests.

Since you say these are your company's own machines that they are looking to slow down, that's stoopid, but not unethical. However, if these were *customer* machines then I'd have to put my foot down. Your boss won't thank you (and may even fire you), but your company would get absolutely **roasted** if/when a customer finds out what is really going on. Doing the right thing for both your company and its customers, against supervisor wishes, is what ethics is all about.

Comment: I appreciate your concern :). Its company computers! Lets just say in this situation doing nothing to solve the problem in lieu of the 'best solution' would be considered very very silly.... it's one of those real world problems where companies don't have infinite money but still need to solve business problems.

Comment: @Justin - OK. Then we are just into stoopid territory. Do warn them about heat issues though. During your testing, I'd suggest getting a CPU temperature montior and verifying that you aren't overheating your target PCs.

Comment: @Justin I don't believe you that it is company computers, because if it was, this would never have been an issue. But here's a good solution. Tell your boss to notify the customer of the issue and also to include any reason(s) why the issue is an annoyance, but not a dealbreaker. Not only will you avoid being dishonest, but your customer might respect you for that honesty. The alternative is to lie and run the risk of being discovered.

Comment: @KyleM Why wouldn't it be an issue? What if you worked at mcDonalds and you noticed that when the screen flickered you could edit ... hm.. lets say your time card. Wouldn't McDonalds be suited to address that loop hole? what if they couldn't upgrade their 130 000 consoles overnight? but they can push code in an afternoon.... Life is not always so black and white! Its actually a really interesting debate and sits on an ethical gray line for sure.

Comment: @Justin In my opinion, it's not an ethically grey area. You're addressing a problem by making more of a problem, for the sole purpose of covering for the original problem source. You're disrupting potential productivity by making the problem bigger, therefore. Productivity and company resources cost money, therefore you're wasting the company's money. Sounds ethical, right?

Comment: @adorablepuppy what if I want to make a machine that wastes time? and I hire people to use the machine and maintain the machine? It seems useless, but I don't see any ethical problem with it at all. It just seems... stupid. In an ideal world all problems could have perfect solutions ... but in real life we have to make compromises. For example: Quantitative easing - it just covers up a larger problem. Is it bad? probably. Is it supposed to help fix a problem and be a lesser of multiple problems? For sure.

Answer (score 0):

You bind a

```
Form2 Form = new Form2();

// open form2
Form.Show();
```

to a

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
//spam form2. Maybe set timer Interval to 10 or 5.
{

}
```

And it will lag intense within 4 min or so. atleast I can't access the task manager.

form2 properties, put opacity 0%, windowsstate = Minimized and don't show in taskbar.

this is an example:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
//spam form2. Maybe set timer Interval to 10 or 5.
{
    Form2 Form = new Form2();

    // open form2
    Form.Show();
}
```